# What does 有节奏地 mean?

Tags: meaning

I search it on web and it means rhythmically.

I thought that 地 always comes after an adjective to make it an adverb but 节奏 is a noun.

Comment: Isn't 有节奏 an adjective?  Would it be possible to give the context please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes 节奏 is a noun, adding 有 making it adjective, i.e. 有节奏的 (rhythmical). And 有节奏地 (rhythmically) is an adverb.

There are other examples like

```
有身份(的) (respectable)
有目的(的) (purposeful / purposive)
有人气(的) (popular)
```